# What's the keyboard hotkey for Blockquote on Mac keyboard?

Tags: discussion, keyboard-shortcuts, blockquote, mac

You can use<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> on Mac to write codes. But you can't use<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> or <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to quote something, is there a hotkey to quote something on Mac keyboard?